# Sax parser read a line not totally

Tags: java, xml, sax, string-parsing

I'm trying to parse a simil-[InkML](http://www.w3.org/TR/InkML) document. Every content's node has more tuple (separated by comma) with 6 or 7 number (negative and decimal too).

In testing I see that the method *character* of SAX don't memorize all the data.

The code:

```
    public class PenParser extends DefaultHandler {

   //code useless

public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {
//begin my debug print
        StringBuilder  buffer=new StringBuilder ();
        for(int i=start;i<length;i++){
            buffer.append(ch[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(">"+buffer);
//end my debug print
```

In debug, I see that *buffer* don't contain all the number of the interested tag, but it contain only the first 107 (more or less) *char* of content of the tag (my rows are not longer that 4610 char): it's strange this cut of *char* by *StringBuffer* and *SAX* parsing, in my opinion.

I had used the StringBuilder too but the problem remain.

Any suggest?

Comment: the cut is random: sometimes doesn't happen, sometime happens after 107 char, sometime after 3000 char: the length of row is not statically defined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes - that's pretty obvious.
characters may be called several times when one node is parsed.

You'll have to use the `StringBuilder` as member, append the content in characters and deal with the content in `endElement`.

**edited**

btw. you do not need to build the buffer character by character - 
this is my implementation of characters (which I always use)

```
    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException
    {
        characters.append(new String(ch,start,length));
    }
```

... and not to forget ....

```
    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException 
    {
                    final String content = characters.toString().trim();
                    // .... deal with content
                    // reset characters
        characters.setLength(0);
    }

 private final StringBuilder characters = new StringBuilder(64);
```

Comment: characters.append(new String(ch,start,length)); saved me

Comment: calling setLength(0) wouldn't work for something like the subcontent in <abc>content<def>subcontent</def>morecontent</abc> though, right?

Comment: no this easy solution wouldn't work then. I think another strategy would be needed then anyway - putting together content + morecontent without subcontent in-between wouldn't make much sense, would it? OK - a solution could be dealing with the content in another method that's both called from startElement and endElement. So - this solution works for me, because I never define XML structures with interleaved content.

Comment: There's no sense for the garbage String. StringBuilder has an append that accepts the same parameters as the characters function (char[], offset, length). I also wouldn't use the trim() since whitespace within the content is considered significant and should be preserved.